# Apply class to child element if sum of children exceed parent width

Tags: jquery, loops, menu, responsive-design, menuitem

I'm trying to create a responsive menu that is limited to one row.  When the screen width gets smaller any menu items that don't completely fit into the row needs to be dropped into a "More" menu item that is fixed to the right in the menu.  I'd normally just do this with CSS media queries but given that the number of menu items is dynamic it's hard to do with media queries.

My original idea is to assign a class to them dynamically this way the class assigned would have a display none and when the "More" button is pushed it will show the hidden elements.

So far I've gotten this far:

```
      var parentWidth = $('nav').width();

      var childrenWidth=0;
        $('.menu-bar li').each( function(){ cWidth += $(this).width(); });

      while (childrenWidth > parentWidth) {               

            $($(".menu-bar li").get().reverse()).each(function() { 
                $(this).addClass('hidden-item');
             });                  
      };
```

This obviously doesn't work, any help would be appreciated.

If anyone knows of a great CSS way to do this I'd love to hear it, I've been racking my brain trying to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: I guess one of the example in this video does this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54wJkqG8jXE .. Somwhere around `20:18`

Comment: Those are some excellent tips, I'm assuming the one you were talking about is the tip for styling based on sibling count.  That would totally work if the siblings weren't variable width.  Thanks for the link to the video I got some great ideas for some other issues I'm working on!